# SocketException and HttpRequestException

Tags: asp.net-core, url, asp.net-web-api, httprequest

I want to connect my asp.net core API project to my asp.net core project. Also, my Asp.net core project is being prepared with an n-layer architecture, I defined a new controller in my presentation layer and wanted to pull the list of employees into it with get-async, but it says I have an error in the section, and I get the errors in the title.

```
var responseMessage = await httpClient.GetAsync("https://localhost:7087/api/Employee /");
```

this is my controller:

> ```
> using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
> using Newtonsoft.Json;
> using System.Net.Http;
> using System.Collections.Generic;
> using System.Threading.Tasks;
> using BlogApiDemo.DataAccessLayer;
> using System.Text;
>
> namespace CoreDemo.Controllers
> {
>     public class EmployeeTestController : Controller
>     {
>         public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
>         {
>             var httpClient = new HttpClient();
>             var responseMessage = await httpClient.GetAsync("https://localhost:7087/api/Employee/");
>             var jsonString = await responseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
>             var values = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Class1>>(jsonString); //json convert .net form
>             return View(values);
>         }
>
>     }
>
>     public class Class1
>     {
>         public int ID { get; set; }
>         public string Name { get; set; }
>     }
> }
> ```

this is my view:

> ```
> @using CoreDemo.Controllers
> @model List<Class1>
> @{
>     ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
>     Layout = "~/Views/Shared/AdminLayout.cshtml";
> }
>
> <table class="table table-bordered">
>     <tr>
>         <th>#</th>
>         <th>Adı Soyadı</th>
>         <th>Sil</th>
>         <th>Düzenle</th>
>     </tr>
>     @foreach(var item in Model)
>     {
>         <tr>
>             <td>@item.ID</td>
>             <td>@item.Name</td>
>         </tr>
>     }
> </table>
> ```

Comment: Hi @İrem Ertürk 1, how is your request api like? And could you pls share the exception you get? Also pls set breakpoint and check which line makes such error.